# How to ignore duplicates in bash history

Tags: bash, macbook-pro

```
Centixels-MacBook-Pro:~ Centixel$ /* some command */
Centixels-MacBook-Pro:~ Centixel$ ./a.out
Centixels-MacBook-Pro:~ Centixel$ ./a.out
Centixels-MacBook-Pro:~ Centixel$ ./a.out
Centixels-MacBook-Pro:~ Centixel$
```

I want to be able to access `/* some command */` in two upkey presses, rather than 4 or N upkey presses. Is this possible to implement in settings? I hate having to upkey a million times through repeat commands to access a previous command.

If this is a repeat question, please refer me, I was not sure how to ask the question. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Centixels-MacBook-Pro:~ Centixel$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Edit:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions
. .alias
alias ducks='du -cks * | sort -rn | head -15'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:/home/username/bin:/usr/local/homebrew
export PATH
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

This is my edited `.bashrc` file (in my home directory), and the changes seem to not have been enacted, I have restarted my terminal as well.

Comment: The `HISTCONTROL` variable in bash appears to do what you want. Ubuntu versions have been setting it to `ignoreboth` in `~/.bashrc` for as long as I can remember. It looks like you are on MacOS instead?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

According to bash manpage:

> A value of `ignoredups` causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved.

Comment: Where do I find the ```.bashrc``` file

Comment: it's located in your home directory.

Comment: @Centixel, you'll need to enable viewing hidden files first, if you want to see it in your file manager. The dot files (starting with ., like .bashrc) are hidden files.